# How to know if a query fails in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, try-catch

Im using Laravel 4 with MySQL and I want to know how to control possible errors when a record is inserted, updated or deleted in DB. For example, if I do an update as follows:

```
DB::table('user')->where('id', $id)->update($userdata);
```

How could I know if that query fails? I thought of using a try-catch block to catch the exception and deal with it but I want to know whether there exists a Laravel specific method.

Comment: When a query fail a PDOException will be thrown. You can catch it.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo, not really. Laravel [overrides it](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L528) and throws a regular `Exception` instead.

Comment: @Raphael_, you are right, thanks for rectifying.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

put it in a try catch block.

```
try {

    DB::table('user')->where('id', $id)->update($userdata);
}catch(\Exception $e){
    //Do something when query fails. 
}
```

moreover,

`DB::insert()` returns boolean.

`DB::update()` returns boolean

`DB::delete()` returns boolean

`DB::insertGetId()` return the last inserted id.

You can write your follow up codes depending upon the value.

**P.S.** The above are not for errors but just to know whether your query *affected* some rows or not.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I think to use try-catch but I'd want to be sure if Laravel provides a direct method. Althoug if that methods return a boolean about if rows were affected that's enough for me.

Comment: `return false` in `catch` block. that's how i made it boolean ;)

Comment: Can we catch PDOException as @Rubens commented in the question?

Comment: @sangam `\Exception $e` is the the PDOException.

Comment: it works like that, but only when added the '/' forward slash. Why does it only work with the forward slash in front of "Exception"?

Comment: Just FYI it's `DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()` in Laravel 5.