# laravel DB insert silent error when insert array key is named wrong

Tags: php, laravel

When inserting `[[..., 'wrong_key_name'=> value,...],...]` as part of a larger array I seem to get nothing.... no error, no insert. This is the call I am using.

```
 DB::connection($dbc)->table($table)->insert($array);
```

Anybody else see this? Obviously I fix it by having the right name.

Comment: Which driver are you using. The thrown error must come from the database and will be (normally) catched by Laravel. This is the case with MySQL and PGSQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424122/how-to-know-if-a-query-fails-in-laravel-4

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an error? Have you checked the log that Laravel fills when an error occurs?

Comment: Answering all the comments.... Luceos - Using Mysql, Anant - that answer works correctly, so technically this question is a duplicate, although I could not find the question in searching, Mjh - I am not a super great log guy... I need things obvious, and that said, I could not find it in the log